# Overlaying data on to a map using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

So, I have created a map of the contiguous USA using ggplot and then made a separate graph(/map) of specific data points within the USA, based upon their long/lat position and I am wondering how one may overlay these specific data points on to the map. Code as follows:

```
america_map <- map_data("world", region='USA')
USA_map <-
  ggplot(america_map, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group)) +
  geom_polygon() + 
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-125,-65)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(25, 50)) + 
  coord_map() +
USA_map

Ravg_map <-
  ggplot(longlat_LH, aes(x=longitude, y=latitude))+
  geom_point(aes(color=Ravg))
Ravg_map
```

The longlat_LH df looks like this for reference:

```
> head(longlat_LH)
 X latitude longitude site_id Ravg
 1    38.42   -108.38     409 40.8
 2    40.17   -107.06     426 40.3
 3    37.79   -108.02     465 37.0
 4    39.06   -108.06     622 43.6
 5    37.75   -107.69     632 41.3
 9    37.65   -108.01     739 39.7
```

Comment: `USA_map + geom_point(data = longlat_LH, aes(x=longitude, y=latitude, color = Ravg))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your geoms directly to `USA_map`, but set the `data=` argument to `longlat_LH`.  Here's an example that uses the `ggrepel` package to space out labels that are close to one another and avoid overlapping:

```
library(ggrepel)

USA_map +
  geom_point(data=longlat_LH,
    mapping=aes(x=longitude, y=latitude, group=NULL),
    color='white'
  ) +
  geom_text_repel(data=longlat_LH,
    mapping=aes(x=longitude, y=latitude, group=1, label=site_id),
    color='white'
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this works perfectly, ive since edited my graph further and it didn't work until I added that 'group=NULL' argument, can you explain what this group term is? im very new to all this as you can probably tell

Comment: The group aesthetic is what `ggplot` is using to display your geoms.  So, for the map, there is a `group` value that's associated with the points that make up that polygon.  In the case of the country, it would be all the points on that border.  If you setup to draw states, it's all the points on the outside of each state... with states like Michigan containing more than one polygon.  In `longlat_LH`, it does not have a "group" column, so you'll get an error (since `ggplot` tries to apply the same aesthetics used for the map).  Setting that to `NULL` just means you don't need a group.

Comment: You can just set it to `group=1` or something like that too - if you set `group=` any number or character that is not a column in your dataset, it just indicates that all observations belong to the same group.  Which doesn't really matter for the point and label/text geoms.